# Replace innerHTML and after HTML with PHP

Tags: php

Hi how can I replace the following content with PHP:

```
<div>innerHTML</div>aferHTML<div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2
```

Afterwards it should be

```
<div>new innerHTML</div>new aferHTML<div>new innerHTML2 </div>new aferHTML2
```

The new is just standing for another value and of course there are more elements.

I know that I require to use:

```
$content ='<div>innerHTML</div>aferHTML<div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2';
$elements = $content->childNodes;
foreach ($elements as $element) {
//replace innerHTML and afterHTML with new text 
}
```

I find a lot of information after about 2 days looking for it, but there is really not any single useful script for it.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal to solve this is based on a few assumptions:

- Your input is HTML, not some random string
- You want to be able to do this with any type of tag - not only divs
- You want to be able to replace both the innerHTML and the outerHTML with unrelated values

Using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) I was able to solve it like this:

```php
$input = '<div>innerHTML</div>aferHTML<div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$output = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//div') as $dom_element) {
    $dom_element->nodeValue = 'new innerHTML';
    $new_tag = $dom_element->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom_element);
    $output .= $new_tag;
    $output .= 'new outerHTML';
}
```

Comment: thanks the code would work if there wouldn`t be child elements within my document. Can you update the document, so that it would work for elements with children as well?

Comment: Adapting the solution to fit your specific needs is up to you; just change the xpath query to get the proper nodes.